# Estrutura de Repetição em Python

Tags: python, loop, while, fatorial

Preciso resolver a seguinte equação em Python

> N é um valor inteiro e positivo. Calcule e mostre o valor de E conforme a fórmula a seguir:
>
> E = 1 + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + ... + 1/N!

Minha tentativa:

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de B: "))
e = 1
i = 1
while (i <= n):
  fat = 1
  j = 1
  while (j <= i):
    fat = fat*j 
    e = e + 1/fat
    break
  break
print("Valor de E = ", e)
```

Comment: Ajuste da pergunta para ficar impessoal e possa auxiliar outras pessoas no futuro também.

Comment: Pode colocar na pergunta pelo menos uma das suas tentativas? Ficará mais fácil identificarmos sua dificuldade.

Comment: Beleza, só um segundo.

Comment: @AlexandreCardoso E então? Desistiu da pergunta?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Perdão, pensei que tinha editado e não foi, agora editei.

Comment: Discordo do fechamento desta questão. A primeira versão dela de fato não estava muito boa, mas atualmente não há nada de errado com ela. Votei pela reabertura.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No python, o `break` não finaliza o laço, e sim o interrompe imediatamente. Diferente de outras linguagens, você não tem uma palavra-chave do tipo `fim-while` ou coisa semelhante. O compilador/interpretador sabe onde o `while` acaba ao olhar a identação.

Além disso, você havia se esquecido de incrementar os valores `i` e `j`.

Um outro erro foi que o `e = e + 1/ fat` deveria estar depois do `while` interno, e não dentro dele.

Outro detalhe é que você está lendo é um valor `N`, e não um valor `B`.

E também coloquei um `print()` a mais para quebrar uma linha antes de mostrar a saída.

Eis como fica o seu código com essas correções:

```
n = int(input("Digite o valor de N: "))
e = 1
i = 1
while (i <= n):
  fat = 1
  j = 1
  while (j <= i):
    fat = fat * j
    j = j + 1
  e = e + 1 / fat
  i = i + 1
print()
print("Valor de E =", e)
```

Quando você informa 25 como o valor de `N`, eis a saída:

> ```
> Valor de E = 2.7182818284590455
> ```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/bQaox0)